# Typechecking inline type hints in Python

Tags: python, decorator, type-hinting, typeguards

Currently I'm using `typeguard.typechecked` to decorate my functions and check inputs and outputs from important functions.

```py
from typeguard import typechecked
@typechecked  # Gives me an error if argument/return types don't match the hints
def takes_int_makes_float(x: int) -> float:
    return float(x)
```

But what if I want to check types coming from functions I cannot control, and error when the type isn't what I want?

```py
@proposed_decorator
def does_something_interesting():
    # Implicitly assert that this is the right type.
    # Note that this is valid Python code already, and works as a hint to my IDE.
    x: float = makes_float_or_tuple()
    print(x)
```

Is there some way to do this? Surely it's possible to implement with a decorator using `ast`.

I'm aware that I can `assert` `isinstance` or something similar, but an automatic implicit approach would be a lot nicer.

### Edit:

As a response to the suggestion of wrapping methods with typing information I'll share my actual use case.

I'm using `torchtyping` to document and ensure the shapes of my PyTorch tensors.

```py
from torchtyping import TensorType
import torch

def interesting_reshaping_method(x: TensorType['batch', 'num_points', 'point_dim']):
    lengths: TensorType['batch', 'num_points', 1] = torch.norm(x, dim=2, keepdim=True)
    # ... do something that requires this exact shape to do what I want,
    # but will fail silently if the shape isn't what I want.
```

In this case I need to explicitly check the type of the tensor, and its shape would be different if for example I had used `keepdim=False` or some different `dim`. It also needs to be brief so I can use it as documentation as well as to catch bugs where they really are happening.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit." ~ python's zen.

Comment: and why not you just make a decorated version of those function you wish to typecheck?

Comment: @Copperfield I'm being very explicit about the behavior I want, I just don't want to have to  type tons of boilerplate. The reason for not using a decorator around the function I want to call is because library functions often don't have type hints. Something like a `typecheck_inline` flag for the `typechecked` decorator would be perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

> "The reason for not using a decorator around the function I want to call is because library functions often don't have type hints"

Then just add type hints to them.

There is at least 2 ways to do it.

The first option is, make a new function for the sole reason of adding the type hint to it you desire, for example:

```
>>> from typeguard import typechecked
>>> from typing import Optional, Tuple, get_type_hints
>>> import mimetypes #our guinea pig for the example :p
>>> get_type_hints(mimetypes.guess_type)
{}
>>> @typechecked
def guess_type_bad(*a,**k) -> Tuple[str,Optional[int]]: #deliberately bad to see that it works
    return mimetypes.guess_type(*a,**k)

>>> guess_type_bad("test.txt")
('text/plain', None)
>>> guess_type_bad("test.tar.gz")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    guess_type_bad("test.tar.gz")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py", line 1019, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(*exc.args) from None
TypeError: type of the return value[1] must be one of (int, NoneType); got str instead
>>>
>>> @typechecked
def guess_type_good(*a,**k) -> Tuple[str,Optional[str]]:
    return mimetypes.guess_type(*a,**k)

>>> guess_type_good("test.tar.gz")
('application/x-tar', 'gzip')
>>>
```

the second option is directly write into their [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__annotations__) special attribute and then decorate it

(this wouldn't work for build-in functions and/or c-extensions, only those created created with pure python, so you can't do this to math.cos or numpy.array for example)

```
>>> mimetypes.guess_type.__annotations__["return"]=Tuple[str,Optional[str]]
>>> guess_type = typechecked(mimetypes.guess_type)  #decoration with "@" is just syntactic sugar for this
>>> guess_type("test.tar.gz")
('application/x-tar', 'gzip')
>>> help(guess_type)
Help on function guess_type in module mimetypes:

guess_type(url, strict=True) -> Tuple[str, Optional[str]]
    Guess the type of a file based on its URL.
    
    [....]

>>>
```

As for some inline version, it seem that that is simple not possible to do it dynamically for functions:
[7.2.2. Annotated assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annassign)

> If a name is annotated in a function scope, then this name is local
> for that scope. Annotations are **never** evaluated and stored in function
> scopes.

with that information lost at run time, no decorator with any amount of hackery can know that a given variable inside a function was annotated somehow, so is just an artifact for static type checkers that can look at the source code directly (such as your IDE), so you would need a compiler to add those type-check in the code for you if you want them at run time... And if you want that, then you probably need to consider if you're better using a different language that offer a native type checking and enforcing mechanism instead.

Beside that, use one of the solution I propose or default to `assert`, `isinstance`, etc... that look like the only way

Comment: Hmm, this is an alright approach for when I want to add typing information to specific functions but I still think I need the API I described in my post. I've updated it to show my exact use case so you can see why it doesn't quite fit the bill.

Comment: in your edit you put "do something that depends on the tensor's shape", that sound like a job for a [dispacher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) if your current function is a bunch of `if` to check the shape, you can try make each branch into its own function and let the dispatcher pick the path according to the type hint, and if the one in the standard library is not enough, you can always make your own by studying the one in standard library

Comment: No, sorry, I don't mean as an if statement. I mean that the shape needs to be right for the rest of the function to work as expected. I updated the comment in that function to clarify.

Comment: can you include an example that actually work to illustrate a couple cases?, "but will fail silently if the shape isn't what I want." mmm if you want to be defensive then you need to be explicit about it and check, otherwise is on the user if he/she get something else for using the thing incorrectly

Comment: Didn't find a good solution for this, but thanks for your effort @Copperfield. I will give you the bounty, and then I'll probably contribute this feature to `typeguard`.

Answer (score -2):

### Installation:

```
pip install runtime-type-checker
```

### Description

You can check an object against a type or an annotation via the check_type function.

The function returns None if the check was successful or raises a TypeError in case of error.

Note that this function does not check recursively for e.g. the attributes of a class.

```
from typing import List, Sequence, Optional, Mapping
from dataclasses import dataclass
from runtime_type_checker import check_type


check_type("a", str)  # OK
check_type(["a"], List[str])  # OK
check_type(["a", 1], Sequence[str])  # raises TypeError


@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int
    b: Optional[Mapping[str, int]] = None


check_type(Foo(1), Foo)  # OK
check_type(Foo(1), int)  # raises TypeError
```

link: https://pypi.org/project/runtime-type-checker/

Comment: what is the difference with  `typeguard` that the OP already use?

Comment: its easy-to-use. in other topics I think `typeguard` is better but here I use this.

Comment: the OP wants to type check variables annotated inside a functions, not what it come in or out of from one, `typeguard` already do that

Comment: answer edited. pls check it again

Comment: I think typeguard can do that too, he want the check work INSIDE a function for an arbitrary variable inside it that was annotated

Comment: The reason I introduced this library was that I was confident it would work perfectly for the current version 3.8. I will not reject your statement after seeing the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/runtime-type-checker/).